# Android Places Picker deprecated, alternative way to show map selection

Tags: android, maps

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
                Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "myapikey");
            }

            // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
            List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

            int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
            // Start the autocomplete intent.
            Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                    AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                    .build(this);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

So I reached to that solution, the problem is that unlike  the previous PlacePicker it is not showing to me Maps. Just a textbox to search for a place, I want same feature like before show the user map and let him select place he wants by moving the marker .

PS I am yet to add Enable Billing Account too.

Answer (score 0):

As you know... Google has rearranged their gms(Maps, Places) libs to GCP (Google Cloud Platform)...

The old versions of libs are not available especially PlacePicker (turned off).

The resolutions are:

1. 3rd party PlacePicker libs.
2. make it by newer libs from scratch.